# C# - Sum List having some null

Tags: c#

In my apps I will need to handle null value in a list.

Is there a way to do a sum in a foreach without using an if statement to check if an item is null in the list.

```
List<int?> numberList = new();
numberList.Add(32);
numberList.Add(21);
numberList.Add(null);
numberList.Add(11);
numberList.Add(89);
int? result = 0;
    
foreach (var item in numberList)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        result += item;
    }   
}
Console.WriteLine($"with if statement Value is : {result}");
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using LINQ's `Sum` method?

Comment: `without using an if statement` why? An `int?` is actually a `Nullable<int>` and a `Nullable<int>` that contains the null value isn't the same as another one that contains the value 0.  No matter what syntax you use, you'll eventually use conditional logic to replace `null` with 0.

Comment: Use a conditional operator instead of an if.  Like this: result+= item.HasValue ? item : 0.  It's still a conditional statement, but not an If, so hopefully that meets your criteria? But honestly, using nullables will at some point require conditional validation to check whether the value exists or not. Using an if is not bad design, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do a sum in a foreach without using an if statement
> to check if an item is null in the list.

Sure, you could use [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=net-6.0):

```
foreach (var item in numberList)
{
    result += item.GetValueOrDefault(); 
}
```

But then you lose the information if there was at least one item != null, because you'd treat a null item same as an item that is 0. Of course you can shorten code with LINQ:

```
int result = numberList.Sum(i => i.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Comment: That still uses a conditional check under the hood. That's cleaner than an explicit check, but the OP's requirement to avoid `if` is a bit unusual

Comment: Parameterless `GetValueOrDefault` (the overload used here) doesn't do the check. It disregards the `hasValue` flag and returns the `value` field. If the flag is false, the value will be default/zero because it can't be anything else.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of LINQs [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0). Just use it in combination with the [Coalescing Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) which allows to specify an explicit default value in case of `null`:

```
int sum = numberList.Sum(n => n ?? 0);
```

or more simple to use 0 as default:

```
int sum = numberList.Sum();
```

Note that you need to define usage of LINQ like

```
using System.Linq;
```

Without LINQ, you can  also make use of the Coalescing Operator:

```
foreach (var item in numberList)
{
    result += item ?? 0;
}
```

Note that this is from a runtime point of view exactly the same like you've showed in your example, it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: I do not want use LINQs

Comment: @Jean-MarcFlamand why? What's your actual question? Whether you use `if` or `??` you are using conditional logic.

Comment: Kind of seems like you're hurting yourself for no reason. Why get wrapped up in the mechanism? Why all the ceremony of the loop when the LINQ method name tells you exactly what it's doing? One line, nothing weird or obtuse; succinct and semantically clear.